# route not recognized by iis

Tags: visual-studio-2013, asp.net-web-api2

I'm trying to use the attribute-based routing in Web Api 2. So I added this:

```
public class PropertyApiController : ApiController
{
    [Route("properties")]
    public IEnumerable<Property> GetAll()
    {
        // return properties
    }
}
```

I also have this in `WebApiConfig`:

```
config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

From my understanding, it should work when I type something like:

```
http://localhost:3648/properties/
```

(`http://localhost:3648` is the IIS express url set in the project properties.)

But when I try to do that I get the error message:

```
HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden
The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory.
```

Whereas I was expecting some kind of json. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try adding <system.webServer>

<`directoryBrowse enabled="true"` />
</system.webServer> in the web.config? Check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15816924/http-error-403-14-forbidden-the-web-server-is-configured-to-not-list-the-conte

Comment: Thanks Spock. I actually decided to use the template and remove/change some items instead of just starting from scratch. Upvoted anyway.