# Difficulties facing in deploying a WCF 3.5 service in iis

Tags: wcf, iis-7, iis-6

I have developed a WCF application in .net framework 3.5. The application is working fine but when I  deploy it in iis it is giving blank when I have tried to access the webservice using the url

```
http://mysite:8086/VpoService.svc
```

my configuration file is like this.

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="VpoService.VpoServiceTypeBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="VpoService.VpoServiceTypeBehavior"
        name="VpoService.VpoServiceType">
        <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="VpoService.IVpoService">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <!--<endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />-->
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: Make sure your application on IIS has his application pool on `Integrated` and not `Classic`.

Comment: if it still don't work it might be because asp.net is not registered on IIS. If that's the case you will need to run the register command with proper parameter that i can't recall but the main command line is `aspnet_regiis` a quick search over the internet should reveal you couple ways to use it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IIS hosted wcf returns me blank page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20958365/iis-hosted-wcf-returns-me-blank-page)

Answer (score 0):

Try modifying your `<endpoint>`

```
<host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://MachineIP/VpoService.svc" />
      </baseAddresses>
</host>
```

It worked for me