# Web server configuration error

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config

I uploaded my website on web server(www.somee.com) but there is an error which I am facing like many other new web developers face. I had done these things to get rid of this error. There is no error when I test my website on local host.

1) I have right clicked on my page named "WebHome.aspx" and make it start page.
2) After reading multiple solution I had tried most of them but still the problem is still there.
My web conf. file have following script

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
    <defaultDocument>
      <files>
        <clear />
        <add value="WebHome.aspx" />
      </files>
    </defaultDocument>
  </system.webServer>

  <authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms loginUrl="WebHome.aspx" defaultUrl="WebHome.aspx"  >
    </forms>
  </authentication>
```

Error: 
HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden
The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory.

Please help and Thanks in advance.

Comment: and... which is the error exactly?

Comment: HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden
The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory.

Comment: a quick google on your error and seems that you need a default document: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15816924/http-error-403-14-forbidden-the-web-server-is-configured-to-not-list-the-conte, read this http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/defaultdocument

Comment: Also try changing WebHome.aspx to index.aspx just to see if that makes a difference