# ASP.NET MVC5 The webserver is not configured for the requested URL, and directory browsing is not enabled on the server

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis

I have an issue with loading the pages from a MVC5 application.

I have this software installed and used:

- Windows 10
- Visual Studio Enterprise 2015
- Microsoft IIS 10.0 Express
- MVC 5 with Entity Framework

Until now everything worked fine and I was able to display the website. 
After creating a model and after that a controller using the entity framework I got this error message.

```
HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden
The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory.

Most likely causes:

    A default document is not configured for the requested URL, and directory browsing is not enabled on the server.


Things you can try:

    If you do not want to enable directory browsing, ensure that a default document is configured and that the file exists.
    Enable directory browsing.
        Go to the IIS Express install directory.
        Run appcmd set config /section:system.webServer/directoryBrowse /enabled:true to enable directory browsing at the server level.
        Run appcmd set config ["SITE_NAME"] /section:system.webServer/directoryBrowse /enabled:true to enable directory browsing at the site level.
    Verify that the configuration/system.webServer/directoryBrowse@enabled attribute is set to true in the site or application configuration file.

Detailed Error Information:
Module     DirectoryListingModule
Notification       ExecuteRequestHandler
Handler    StaticFile
Error Code     0x00000000
Requested URL      http://localhost:2063/
Physical Path      c:\users\johan\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\MvcMovie2\MvcMovie2
Logon Method       Anonymous
Logon User     Anonymous
Request Tracing Directory      C:\Users\johan\Documents\IISExpress\TraceLogFiles\MVCMOVIE2
```

So first I started with the suggestions the error message is giving me.

These both worked fine.
 - cd into the IIS Express install directory
 - `appcmd set config /section:system.webServer/directoryBrowse /enabled:true`

Then I tried to run this command:
`appcmd set config ["SITE_NAME"] /section:system.webServer/directoryBrowse /enabled:true`

Where I replaced `["SITE_NAME"]` with:
- `["SITE_NAME"]`
- `["localhost"]`
- `["MovieDb2"]`
- `"MovieDb2"`
- `[MovieDb2]`
- `MovieDb2`
None of them worked and I got an error message:
`ERROR ( message:Cannot find SITE object with identifier ["SITE_NAME"]`

I have been able to find a lot of documentation, but that all goes back to `.ASPX` format and older versions of IIS Express.

In Visual Studio I right clicked on one of the index.cshtml files of the application and clicked "Set as start page"
This didn't work, even after a rebuild.

Next I found some information that you would have to make some changes in IIS manager. I have searched a lot, but I am not able to find IIS manager.
Even using this link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/library/bb763170.aspx
The command `inetmgr` only returns an error.

To Web.config I added this code:

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
</system.webServer>
```

That didn't solve the problem either.

After that I followed the steps from this page: [HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15816924/http-error-403-14-forbidden-the-web-server-is-configured-to-not-list-the-conte)

But there I also have to get into the IIS manager, which I am not able to find.

I really hope someone has a solution for this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sounds like ASP.NET MVC is not registered properly on IIS Express, which is weird. You will have to use a tool such as Jexus Manager to check application pool settings to see if CLR version 4 is configured.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your root directory is empty?(index.html,index.aspx vb.) and I think Your project web.config default document property is not set.

Directory Browse Web.config properties

```
    <configuration>

  <location path="special_directory_name_here">
   <system.webServer>
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
   </system.webServer>

  </location>
</configuration>
```

**Please configure to your project default route settings, because your default route settings, is not redirect to controller.**

**Change Default route settings**

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/prakasht/archive/2013/08/08/change-the-default-route-in-asp-net-mvc.aspx

Default Document Property web.config

```
<configuration>
   <system.webServer>
    <defaultDocument>
        <files>
            <add value="index.php" />
        </files>
    </defaultDocument>
   </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out. 
All I had to do was change the url in RouteConfig.cs

from
`url: "{controller}/{action}/{name}/{id}"`
to
`url: "{controller}/{action}",`

Answer (score 0):

**This is a quick solution for quick app testing purposes and not intended for solving the root cause - not MVC**:

- Errors when the ASP.NET application starts at http://localhost:port#/
- Works when the url changed to http://localhost:45269/HTMLPageName.html

Answer (score 0):

Here's what resolved my specific problem:

From Visual Studio, right click on the Website Project > Properties > Web > Select "Specific Page" > Browse > Select the Default page.

If you're using MVC 5 or higher, make sure that you remove move ".cshtml" and remove the Views directory.  For example, the directory will show as Views/ControllerName/Index.cshtml.  Remove Views so it shows as ControllerName/Index

Answer (score 0):

My problem went away once I added a specific map route to RouteConfig.cs in the App_start folder

'routes.MapRoute("Buy lands", // string name
                  "BuyLands/Index",  // string Url
                   new { controller = "BuyLands", Action = "Index" });

// controller name is BuyLands'