# All requests denied with a 403 after restarting a web app

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have a web app on Azure. Up until a couple of hours ago, it was working perfectly: i could deploy, restart, stop, restart, etc and it would work as expected.

I decided to scale up, changing from S1 Standard to S2 Standard. Now, if I restart my app after I deploy it, or stop and restart, the app seems to enter some kind of a lockdown mode and all requests are blocked with a 403.

One of the detailed error pages says "A default document is not configured for the requested URL, and directory browsing is not enabled on the server.", so I went to IIS manager and *disabled* default documents. The app seemed to have restarted automatically, and it started working again.

However, after restarting, all requests were denied again!

Anybody has any idea of what could be going on?

Comment: Have you attempted to redeploy to a new Web App? (I realize that's a Band-Aid, and not the root cause, but just curious if the code base you have can still be deployed as-is, functionally)

Answer (score 0):

> Anybody has any idea of what could be going on?
>
> so I went to IIS manager and disabled default documents.

I assume that action causes the 403 error. I also can repro it if I disable the default documents with [IIS  remote manager](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/iis-manager).
Please have a try to enable it. I also find a smilar [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33828225/asp-net-mvc5-the-webserver-is-not-configured-for-the-requested-url-and-director).

**Update:**

We could troubleshoot it with the following ways:

1. Add a default document in the default document list and republish it again.
2. Scale service plan down and Scal up to S2.
3. Create a new serviceplan and move the WebApp to the new serviceplan.
4. If all of those can't solve the issue, we also could connect to the Azure support team for help.

Comment: It happens even with def docs enabled. Things is that before scaling up I did not have this problem, and I never used def docs.

Comment: We could troubleshoot it with the following ways: 1. Add a default document  in the default document list and republish it again. 2. Scale service plan down and Scal up to S2. 3. Create a new serviceplan and move the WebApp to the new serviceplan. 4. If all of  those can't resolve the issue, we also could connect to the Azure support team for help.

Comment: a comment would have been a better option for what you have written.

Comment: @It'satrap Thank you for your suggestion. I have updated the answer.

Comment: If I add an Index.html to the root, then my request returns that page, but I get 404 for all controllers. It is like it is not registering any of my routes.

Comment: Have you try the troubleshoot ways? If all of those way can't solve the issue, we also could connect to the Azure support team for help.